# How to use NavHostFragment with FragmentContainerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-architecture-navigation, android-viewbinding

I’m curious about an issue I’m having with Navigation Component, specifically on hosting `NavHostFragment`. I have a single-Activity native app with a few Fragments. I’m in the launcher’s xml, replacing the `<fragment>` with  `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`.

The initial implementation has worked as intended for a year. While introducing the FragmentContainerView this week the starting destination’s screen doesn’t render at launch. Yet I observe logs that prove successful data incoming from network and cache. From this state, only triggering configuration change by rotating the device renders UI as expected.

My AndroidX NavigationFragmentKtx and NavigationUiKtx dependencies are version `2.3.2`. Relevant files abbreviated. Does anything stand out that I've missed? Any thoughts are appreciated.

**launcher_activity.xml**

```xml
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/launcher_navHost"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

**LauncherActivity.kt**

```kotlin
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.launcher_activity) {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: LauncherActivityBinding
    
    private val navController: NavController by lazy {
        val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(
            R.id.launcher_navHost
        ) as NavHostFragment
        navHost.navController
    }
        
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewBinding = LauncherActivityBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `AppCompatActivity(R.layout.launcher_activity)`, which means you are automatically calling `setContentView(R.layout.launcher_activity)` as part of `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` (that's what passing a layout ID does). You're then overriding that layout with a second call to `setContentView()`.

You can just remove the `R.layout.launcher_activity` part if you're using View Binding as it is not needed (and the root of your issue):

```
class LauncherActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```